# How to show a dialog on top of a locked screen with Jelly Bean

Tags: android

I have an Eclair based app that shows a full screen dialog on a locked phone. The dialog appears, and once the dialog disappears (because a user clicked a button on it), the locked screen is shown to the user for them to enter a passcode. All desired behaviour.

This is the snippet that works

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog);
```

When I install this app on a Nexus 7 with Jelly Bean, I do not get the same behaviour. The tablet wakes up and shows the locked screen for the user to enter a passcode. No dialog is presented on top of the locked screen. I enter the passcode and I still do not see the dialog anywhere. Has the way to accomplish the same behaviour changed in a recent release? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'd say that's what's excepted. An app should never be able to override the lockscreen and put dialogs on top of it. That kinda takes away the security aspect of having a lockscreen.

Comment: There are some scenarios where you want this behavior, for example an alarm that you should be able to snooze.

Comment: Android does allow this, it works on my phones. It does not however work on my new Nexus 7 tablet. (By the way, the phone is still locked with a lockscreen. All the user can do is see and interact with the single dialog, and once they do, they are presented with the lockscreen. They cannot do anything else with the phone unless they go through the lockscreen.